# TCPDF producing errors when passing SVG using data uri for images

Tags: php, svg, fabricjs, tcpdf, data-uri

I'm using FabricJS on the front-end in order to design monograms and the images uploaded to the canvas are cropped to fit the design. Fabric uses the source image when generating the SVG, so I am updating the image source to the data uri and rendering the canvas before finally calling toSVG()

The above works, needs tweaking, but the SVG is being generated and looks good.

Now when we pass SVG data to TCPDF, TCPDF throws errors and builds an incomplete PDF. Everything except for the embedded image is drawn correctly. The image portion, however, is just a white square.

What is causing TCPDF to fail parsing the data-uri image?

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'masked' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7145

Warning: Illegal string offset 'altimgs' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7151

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 20877

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 20890

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7153

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7188

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in /home/xxx/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7235
```

Link to the SVG data: http://pastebin.com/SqjYT89Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue is being caused by a bug in FabricJS. The SVG file that you produced using FabricJS has many instances of the `stroke-dasharray` parameter being used in the `stroke` attribute of the `path` tags, except it fails to include any option specification, which is, according to the SVG specs, wrong:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties

The file contains many instances that look like this:

```
style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt;...
```

But should actually look like this:

```
style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt;...
```

Note the addition of the **none** option after `stroke-dasharray`.

To test this theory I did a simple search and replace on the SVG file that you provided, adding the **none** option and once I did that, I was able to successfully convert your SVG file into a JPG using Imagick (got the purple oval with the URL and the picture of the beautiful dog. :-). Based on that result, I'm pretty confident that the TCPDF errors will go away if this issue in the SVG file is resolved.

The proper solution to this problem is to raise an issue in the FabricJS project on GitHub and, if your JavaScript skills are up to it, you could probably make the fix and submit a pull request.

In the meantime, you could work around the issue by running the incoming SVG file through the `str_replace()` function, replacing all instances of `stroke-dasharray: ;` with `stroke-dasharray: none;` before you pass the SVG data into TCPDF and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Still getting the same messages. The SVG and JPG generate fine, but when it comes to TCPDF, it's a no go.

This is the call I'm making to add the SVG:

`ImageSVG( $input_file, 2.5, 25.1, 101.6, 77.6, $link = '', $align = '', $palign = '', $border = 0, $fitonpage = false );`

$input_file being the path to the SVG

Comment: Hmmm... which version of TCPDF are you using? I created a standalone script to add the SVG file to a blank page using the line above, using TCPDF 6.2.12 (the latest as at time of writing) and there were no errors thrown. If you're not on the latest version of TCPDF, try updating and see if that fixes the problem. If that isn't the problem, then let me know what platform you're on and what version of PHP and Imagick you're using.

Comment: 6.0.085, I'll give an update a try. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've updated to the latest available TCPDF, 6.2.12. Still seeing the illegal string messages.

I'm on PHP Version 5.4.39
ImageMagick 6.2.8 05
imagick module version 3.1.2

Comment: The next thing I would try is running an isolated test. When I run this code (http://pastebin.com/HFp7idn8) with this version of your svg (http://pastebin.com/MVvtPfGx) I don't get any errors. I'm using the same versions of stuff, except I'm on PHP 5.6.15. I don't think there are any changes between 5.4 and 5.6 that would be relevant in this case though. So try running this test code (after you've changed the paths to the input and output files) and let me know if you still get the warnings.

Comment: And if you are still getting the warnings, can you chuck the output into a paste so I can see the revised line numbers where the warnings are happening. Thanks.

Comment: No errors generated when I tested your sample code, however, image doesn't make it to the PDF. I see a white square. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: I assume you use the version of the svg file that had the stroke-dasharray attribute fixed? I'm pretty curious about this problem, so let me know if you are comfortable using Composer and git and I will create a github repo with a sample project that we can both work from. Also, you said you were using PHP 5.4, but what operating system are you using? I'm thinking that maybe the Imagick build on that platform might be the culprit.

Comment: You're right about the environment, I decided to try the example code on a production environment and it worked successfully. On development, it fails

Comment: The dev server is CentOS 5.6, PHP 5.4, "ImageMagick 6.2.8 05/07/12 Q16". The production server is CentOS 6.7, PHP 5.5, "ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2015-07-29 Q16"

Comment: Cool. Seeing as how we now know the sample code works on the later version of PHP and Imagick, there's not much point in me replicating that finding. What would be really nice to know is if the full version of your code that was throwing all those warnings works on a server with the same versions of stuff. The obvious way to go about this would be to upgrade your dev server, but I realise that sometimes there are reasons why this can't happen. Anyway, if you do end up finding that the svg fix solved your problem, it would be great if you accepted this answer as the solution.